# Use @redis/json node library to store json objects

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, redis

I tried to use the "@redis/json" library to set json object in Redis.

```
    const redisClient = await createClient({
                url: `redis://${redis.host}:${redis.port}`,                
            });
            await redisClient.connect();
            redisClient.json.set()  //getting json undefined  error
```

But redisClient doesn't recognize the json object.
The docs are not clear

Answer (score 4):

@Simon answer is correct when installing the entire 'redis' library.
This answer works when importing only the @redis/client + @redis/json

```
import { createClient } from '@redis/client';
import RedisJsonModule from '@redis/json';

const redisClient = createClient({
            url: `redis://${redisConfig.host}:${redisConfig.port}`,
            socket: { tls: true },
            modules: { json: RedisJsonModule },
        });
await redisClient.connect();
```

if you are using typescript the redisClient type is RedisClientType<{ json: typeof RedisJsonModule }, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts>

Comment: ^^ use this if you want to pick and choose parts of the redis client.  I gave you an upvote @omer727

Comment: This type was so useful to have autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

The documentation definitely needs work, and that's something we're putting time into.  There are several example scripts here that we try to keep up to date with all the new functionality:

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master/examples

Here's an example of how to use the JSON commands:

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/examples/managing-json.js

Your code looks OK to me, you shouldn't need to `await` the `createClient` call though.

Here's a basic working example:

output:

```
$ node index.js
{
  hello: 'world',
  nums: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
  obj: { hello: 'there', age: 99 }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nrjson",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Simon Prickett",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "redis": "^4.6.7"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

await client.connect();
await client.del('noderedis:jsondata');

// Store a JSON object...
await client.json.set('noderedis:jsondata', '$', {
  hello: "world",
  nums: [ 0, 1, 2, 3],
  obj: {
    "hello": "there",
    "age": 99
  }
});

// And retrieve it....
console.log(await client.json.get('noderedis:jsondata', '$'));

await client.quit();
```

Comment: Your code works when installing  the entire 'redis' library. I've tried  to install  only the 'redis-client' library

Comment: Ah you'd need to also install the JSON package if you're looking to have a minimal installation https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master/packages/json

Comment: The link you  sent is missing the most important part. How to do  the CreateClient itself. I think my answer should be part of the docs